# Smooth curve and smooth surface

Tags: multivariable-calculus

I have question about smooth curve and surface. My textbook defines two theorems related to the smoothness as follows.

**Smooth Curve**
Let $F$ be a real-valued function of class $C^1$ on an open set in $\mathbb{R}^2$, and let $S = \{(x,y) : F(x,y) = \overline{0}\}$. If $a \in S$ and $\nabla F(\overline{a}) \neq \overline{0}$, there is a neighborhood $N$ of $\overline{a}$ such that $S \cap N$ is the graph of a $C^1$ function $f$.

**Smooth Surface**
 Let $F$ be a real-valued function of class $C^1$ on an open set in $\mathbb{R}^2$, and let $S = \{(x,y,z) : F(x,y,z) = \overline{0}\}$. If $a \in S$ and $\nabla F(\overline{a}) \neq \overline{0}$, there is a neighborhood $N$ of $\overline{a}$ such that $S \cap N$ is the graph of a $C^1$ function $f$.

My question is that these two theorems requires that $F$ must be differentiable at every points on $F$ and it must not be equal to 0. Then, what happens if $\nabla F = 0$ at certain point?? I guess that point should be critical point but what I am confused is that the book also says that $\nabla F = 0$ allows possiblility of non-smoothness. 
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's consider the first theorem. If $\nabla F(x,y)=0$ at the point $(x,y)$, then the theorem may fail to hold. For instance, take the function $F(x,y)=y^2-x^2$. We have that

$\frac{\partial F}{\partial x} = -2x,$

and

$\frac{\partial F}{\partial y} = 2y.$

You see that $\nabla F(0,0) = (0,0)$, so that $(0,0)$ is a critical point.

The set $S$ will be

$S=\{(x,y)\ |\ y^2-x^2=0\}=\{(x,y)\ |\ y^2=x^2\} = \{(x,y)\ |\ y=x\text{ or }y=-x\}.$

When you plot the set $S$, it will be the two straight lines $y=x$ and $y=-x$ that intersect each other at the origin, and no matter which small neighborhood of $(0,0)$ you choose, you will always get this picture. These "crossed lines" can of course never be the graph of a real-valued, single-argument function $f$.

As for your other question, that $\nabla F = 0$ "allows possibility of non-smoothness", I don't know what your book means by this. You have assumed that $F$ is differentiable everywhere, and even if $\nabla F = 0$, this does not somehow contradict that $F$ is differentiable or smooth. It *could* mean that if $\nabla F(x,y) = 0$, then the plot of the set $\{(x,y)\ |\ F(x,y)=0\}$ need not be "nice", as my example above shows.

Comment: so your se $S$ cannot be considered as smooth at the origin right?? but how do I determine where the graph is not smooth?? I think there might be a point that is not smooth and not a critical point. is there a way to see where those points are??

Comment: I wouldn't speak of the set $S$ as smooth or non-smooth. It is a set, not a function. I don't understand your questions - your function $F$ is *assumed* to be $C^1$. Can you perhaps elaborate? @eChung00

Comment: But a function is a set or ordered pairs in this case. So $S$ in your example, $S$ is set of pair $(x,y)$ such that $y^2 - x^2 = 0$ is satisfied. So $S$ can be considered as graph of two lines intersecting at the origin, isn't it? Therefore, the graph is not smooth around the origin, right? Then, my question is if there is other way to determine this non-smooth region without finding the critical point as in your example. hope I wrote this understandably. Thanks for your answer by the way.

Comment: @eChung00 yes, in case $S$ can be considered as a graph of some function $f$, then you can speak of the function $f$ as being smooth or not. But it is not always that $S$ can be considered as a graph of a function - for instance when $S$ is two lines intersecting at the origin. No function has this as a graph, which is why I am not sure what is meant by $S$ is smooth, or $S$ is not smooth. In this case, $S$ cannot be represented as the graph of a function, so I wouldn't know how to talk about, if $S$ is smooth or not.

Comment: @eChung00 regarding determining the non-smooth region without finding critical points: You know from your theorems that if you have a point $a$ at which the gradient is non-zero, then $S$ *is* the graph of some differentiable function. This tells you that you can only have some awkward looking $S$ in cases where you have critical points for $F$. Does this answer your questions? Let me know, if I understand you correctly.